# How to remove last 6 directories from a path

Tags: find, filenames

For a requirement I have to purge from directory test3 to test8 , i.e last 6 directories .

```
[testuser@test4 logs]$ pwd
/util/team4/logs

drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test1
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test2
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test3
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test4
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test5
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:17 test6
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser team4     0 Nov 30 01:18 files_between_7
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser team4     0 Nov 30 01:18 files_between_8
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:18 test7
drwxr-xr-x 2 testuser team4  4096 Nov 30 01:18 test8
```

Can you please suggest how to do this .

Comment: Sorry I couldn't make it formatted .

Comment: Not formatted is not a big problem. A bigger lack is the 'what did I already try? Where did I get stuck?'. (U&L is not a script writing service, but we are happy to assist and point out the flaws in your own script or help getting them to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
ls -dt */ |head -n 6| xargs -I{} rm -vr {}
```

or you can use:

```
find ./* -type d  -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort | head -n 6 | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'  | xargs -I{} rm -vr {}
```

this will work with Folders which has spaces in there names

for removing all directories but first 6

```
find ./* -type d  -print | sort | tail -n +7 |  awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | xargs -I{} rm -vr {}
```

Comment: parsing output from ls is icky though. The format is not guaranteed to be stable and likely subject to aliasses. find is better for that (e.g. starting with something like `find . -type d -depth 1 -print` (or -print0 in case of special chars, spaces, ...)

Comment: that's write i edit the answer and i used find ./* to exclude the current directory

Comment: Thanks a lot , above worked . Also if you could suggest same to keep last 6 directories and purge all others directories .

Comment: i edited the answer and added command to what you want

Comment: That is not working . Probably I unable to clear it to you . I want to keep last 6 directories i.e from test3 to test8 and want to purge all the other directories in above case test1 and test2 . If you could help here . Thanks again .

Comment: am sorting the result depending on time, do you wanna sort depending on directories name ?

Comment: yes , depending on directories name .

Comment: ok i edit for you

Comment: Thanks , For the same requirement , now I have to keep last 6 directories and rest need to purged i.e from test3 to test8  >> this logs need to keep intact  and want to purge all the other directories . If you suggest the same  with the coding .

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the 6 last directories in ls using this command

```
ls -l |tail -n 6|tr -s " " " "|cut -d " " -f 9 |xargs rm -R
```

- `tail -n 6` will give you the last 6 directories from the list
- `tr -s " " " "` will convert many spaces to one space
- `cut -d " " -f 9` will extract the names of the directories
- `xargs rm -R` xargs will pass the names of the 6 directories to the command rm -R

Comment: this won't work with files which has spaces in its name